# Сделать множество содержаний как в каталоге, используя 1 активити (java (не клиент-серверное))

Tags: java, android-studio

Учусь делать приложения. В данное время пытаюсь сделать приложение эдакий soundboard.

Есть кнопка, нужно чтобы она раскрывала содержание. И для каждой кнопки своё содержание. Как это реализовать?

Изучал фрагменты, не устраивает то, что для них нужно создавать xml+class для каждого. Можно ли реализовать такую фичу, придерживаясь концепции наименьшей нагрузки и маленький размер приложения?

Comment: есть ExpandableListView для таких задач

Answer (score 0):

Можно реализовать только два фрагмента: Фрагмент, содержащий список кнопок и фрагмент, отображающий содержание кнопки. 
Содержание кнопок можно хранить в локальной базе.
Контент во фрагменте содержания должен обновлять при открытии фрагмента, напр. в методе [Fragment#onViewCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle))

см. также [Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)